# Total left position of absolute div in relative div?

Tags: css, mootools

I have got the following code:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bG2QS/)

```
.item {
    width: 120px;
    padding: 10px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #CCC;
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
    position: relative;
}

.item .item-preview {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
    display: block;
}

.item .item-content {
    /*display: none;*/
   position: absolute;
   left: 0px;
   top: 37px;
   padding: 5%;
   z-index: 11;
   width: 90%;
   background-color: #000;
   color: #FFF;
}
```

I want the div ".item-content", when its displayed, is always on the left side and is as wide as the whole page, how can I do that?

Comment: Left side of what? the relative div? Or the screen? And it should fill up till the right edge?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `position: relative` from `.item`, you will have the desired effect. I also removed the `top: 37px;` to fix the vertical positioning. If you need to tweak that, use `margin-top` instead

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ByRKX/2/)